# Android BLE setValue writing wrong value

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a characteristic to send and receive data through BLE, from an Android phone to a Nordic nRF51 device.

BLE has CRC codes implemented and uses packet retransmission, so data transfers can be considered reliable.

However, the Android sometimes fails to write to the characteristic, even though I check if the write operation has been successfull.

Android code:

```
byte value[] = new byte[3 + transaction.data.length];
value[PKT_ID] = transaction.id; //Event ID
value[PKT_TWI_WRITE_DEVADD] = transaction.deviceAddress; //Address

for (int i = 0; i < transaction.data.length; i++)
    value[i + PKT_TWI_WRITE_DATA] = transaction.data[i];

while(!charac.setValue(value) || (value[PKT_ID]&0xFF) != ((charac.getValue())[PKT_ID]&0xFF));

charac.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);

boolean status = false;
while(!(status = gattInstance.writeCharacteristic(charac)));

System.out.println("Sent id " + (value[PKT_ID]&0xFF) + " char val:" + ((charac.getValue())[PKT_ID]&0xFF) );
```

Example output:

```
I/System.out: Sent id 2 char val:2
I/System.out: Sent id 3 char val:169
I/System.out: Sent id 4 char val:4
I/System.out: Sent id 5 char val:5
```

What may be causing this, and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root of the problem and successfully solved it.

I was using one single characteristic to do bidirectional communication. However, due to the speeds I was trying to achieve, the sequence `setValue()`>`writeCharacteristic` could no longer be considered atomic. What was happening was that the android phone was receiving a notification between  `setValue` and `writeCharacteristic`, changing the value the phone itself would write to the characteristic.

The problem was solved buy using two separate characteristics, one for each communiction direction.